# In Spider-Man: Far From Home, why don't people realise what's going on in the end?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home, mysterio

In the end battle of *Far From Home* there's a part when Mysterio

> turns off the illusions and people can see the drones. How don't they understand that the Elementals are fake?

Comment: Elementals are big. Drones are small.

Comment: The drones in the movie do not seem small at all, yes, smaller than the Elementals, but it seems that they are visible even from a distance.

Answer (score 8):

The general public didn't know that Mysterio was a master of illusions, or that he was a villain.

You might argue that it should've been obvious that the Elemental attacking London Bridge was an illusion when it disappeared, and the drones became visible instead. But that Elemental was presented as a smoke-like entity which appeared out of nowhere to begin with, supposedly having come from another dimension. So it's not unreasonable to think that something like that could disperse and vanish back to the dimension it came from, shortly after Mysterio -- someone widely believed to be a hero -- had shown up and started attacking it. After all, he'd been seen to repel other Elementals in a similar fashion, earlier in the film.

In fact, it was Mysterio himself who gave the order for the illusion of the Elemental to be fully shut down, implying that he already knew how he was going to spin that to make it fit the narrative he wanted to sell to the general public.

> MYSTERIO: Kill it, just kill the illusion. Kill it.
>
> WILLIAM GINTER RIVA: I'm not gonna kill it. They'll see!
>
> MYSTERIO: They'll see what I want them to see!

Also, Mysterio's associate, [William Ginter Riva](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/William_Ginter_Riva), was on the scene, recording video footage of what happened, and a week after the attack on London Bridge, he sent a doctored tape to the media in which Mysterio claimed credit for having driven the Elemental back through the dimensional rift, and portrayed Spider-Man as being behind the drones.

> PAT KIERNAN: We come to you now with revelations about last week's attack in London. An anonymous source provided this video. It shows Quentin Beck, aka, Mysterio, moments before his death. A warning: You may find this video disturbing.
>
> [Cut to altered footage of the Tower Bridge battle.]
>
> MYSTERIO: **I managed to send the Elemental back through the dimensional rift, but I don't think I'm gonna make it off this bridge alive. Spider-Man attacked me for some reason! He has an army of weaponized drones, Stark technology. He's saying he's the only one who's gonna be the new Iron Man, no one else!**
>
> E.D.I.T.H.: Are you sure you want to commence the drone attack? There will be significant casualties.
>
> SPIDER-MAN: Do it. Execute them all.

It was clear to us as the viewers that this was a pack of lies, but the general public didn't have access to nearly as much information as we did.

Comment: I understand that was the plan, but after he killed the illusion there were suddenly lots of drones where the Elemental was, people just assumed they were behind it or something?